# Youtube - downloading a playlist - youtube-dl

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to download all the videos from the [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vy8970q0Xc&list=PLwJ2VKmefmxpUJEGB1ff6yUZ5Zd7Gegn2):

I am using youtube-dl for this and the command is:

```
youtube-dl -citk –format mp4 –yes-playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vy8970q0Xc&list=PLwJ2VKmefmxpUJEGB1ff6yUZ5Zd7Gegn2
```

But this only downloads the first video. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Note to anyone viewing this, youtube-dl is no longer maintained, but luckily [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/wiki/Installation) maintains feature parity with youtube-dl and extends it, and from my experience, is a good alternative.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

In a shell, `&` is a special character, advising the shell to start everything up to the & as a process in the background. To avoid this behavior, you can put the URL in quotes. See the [youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) for more information.

Also beware of `-citk`. With the exception of `-i`, these options make little sense. See the [youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#do-i-always-have-to-pass--citw) for more information. Even `-f mp4` looks very strange.

So what you want is:

```
youtube-dl -i -f mp4 --yes-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vy8970q0Xc&list=PLwJ2VKmefmxpUJEGB1ff6yUZ5Zd7Gegn2'
```

Alternatively, you can just use the playlist ID:

```
youtube-dl -i PLwJ2VKmefmxpUJEGB1ff6yUZ5Zd7Gegn2
```

Comment: what about this C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\New folder>youtube-dl -i PLD07B2225BB40E582
[youtube:playlist] PLD07B2225BB40E582: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: PLD07B2225BB40E582
[youtube:playlist] playlist PLD07B2225BB40E582: Downloading 0 videos
[download] Finished downloading playlist: PLD07B2225BB40E582
//says finished downading but nothing is downloaded.

Comment: @userqrqh123 That sounds like a different question. Go ahead and [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)! Don't forget to include the output when you add the `-v` option, because that will be vital in identifying where your problem is. `youtube-dl -i PLD07B2225BB40E582` works fine for me.

Comment: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\youtube-dl>youtube-dl -i PLD07B2225BB40E582
[youtube:playlist] PLD07B2225BB40E582: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Fundamentals of Physics II with Ramamurti Shankar
[youtube:playlist] playlist Fundamentals of Physics II with Ramamurti Shankar: Downloading 25 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 25
[youtube] NK-BxowMIfg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NK-BxowMIfg: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] NK-BxowMIfg: Extracting video information
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1. Electrostati.......

Comment: @userqrqh123 As I said, a comment is not the place to discuss your unrelated problem. Please ask a question instead. In that question, please do include the output you get when you add `-v`. Also, you should probably decide which of the two outputs you are seeing right now - they are markedly different.

Comment: youtube-dl -x -i <PLAYLIST_ID> worked for me to convert a playlist into audio!

Comment: I also used `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: to find the list id for use with -i, copy the ID after 'playlist='

Comment: Is there is way to Join them in one file after download ?

Comment: Is it possible to download directly to mp3?

Comment: Nice tip about grabbing just the playlist id - hadn't thought of that, thanks!

Comment: For a moment I thought you started the post saying: 'In a nut Shell'. Sorry I know this type of comment is not for Stacked :)

Comment: does --watched argument really work?

Answer (score 39):

I found the best solution after many attempts at solving this problem.

Installation and usage;

**For Windows users:**

Script:

```
youtube-dl --ignore-errors --format bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 160K --output "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={your-youtube-playlist-id}
```

- Download youtube-dl.exe file from [the offical site](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html).
- Dowload ffmpeg from [the offical site](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for convert WebM to MP3 ([Recomended build version](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds))
- Exctract all zip files and move youtube-dl.exe, ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe files to the folder that where you want the downloaded MP3 files.
- Open cmd (Windows terminal) in same folder.
- Replace the script `{your-youtube-playlist-id}` parameter with your YouTube playlist id.
- Run the script.

**For macOS/Linux users:**

Script:

```
youtube-dl --ignore-errors --format bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 160K --output "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={your-youtube-playlist-id}'
```

- Open terminal and if you don't have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), install it. (Linux users can skip this step.)
- Run `brew install youtube-dl ffmpeg` and install youtube-dl and ffmpeg for convert WebM to MP3. (Installation may take longer to install other dependencies.) (For Linux users: `install youtube-dl ffmpeg`)
- Open a terminal in the folder where you want to download the MP3 files.
- Replace the script `{your-youtube-playlist-id}` parameter with your YouTube playlist id.
- Run the script.

Comment: Did the trick. But had to pass in only the playlist ID

Comment: Just say Linux users have to install youtube-dl and ffmpeg. There are many different distributions and only Debian uses apt.

Comment: @Kleysley That's right, I've updated my answers. Thanks for information.

Comment: Recommending `-o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s"` for numbered files

Comment: The asker didn't want to know how to download the audio (though useful) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48425625/1436129 is the right answer. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: @aubreypwd You're welcome. It didn't completely fix my problem when I tried the same thing. Then I read youtube-dl documentation and tried many things and found this solution. Hope this helps other people as well.

Answer (score 16):

I have tried everything above, but none could solve my problem. I fixed it by updating the old version of youtube-dl to download playlist. 
To update it

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

or

```
youtube-dl -U
```

after you have successfully updated using the above command

```
youtube-dl -cit https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLttJ4RON7sleuL8wDpxbKHbSJ7BH4vvCk
```

Comment: If no autoupdate allowed (after removing installed one) use: `sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` and 
`sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

Comment: You should never run youtube-dl with sudo!

Answer (score 15):

### Some commands which you may find useful  while downloading a  playlist

##### Download a playlist

```
youtube-dl <playlist link>
```

##### Best quality video and best quality audio (merged ) + preferred resolution

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]' <playlist link>
```

> This command will download  videos in 1080p resolution if 1080p is available otherwise it will download the next best (less than 1080p) resolution. Here, You can use 480 or 720, etc instead of 1080.
>
> Note: Make sure that ‘FFmpeg’ is installed, otherwise video and audio will not be merged.

##### Best quality video and best quality audio (merged )  + preferred resolution + Add video upload date on the file name

```
youtube-dl -o "[%(upload_date)s] %(title)s.%(ext)s" -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]'  <playlist link>
```

##### Best quality video and best quality audio (merged ) + Preferred resolution + Add video upload date on the file name + Add uploader name on the file name

```
youtube-dl -o "[%(upload_date)s] %(title)s [%(uploader)s].%(ext)s" -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]' <playlist link>
```

> #### Subtitle

##### Best quality video and best quality audio (merged ) + Preferred resolution + Download auto-generated Subtitle

```
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]'  <playlist link>
```

##### Best quality video and best quality audio (merged ) + Preferred resolution + Download video creator’s uploaded subtitle

```
youtube-dl --write-sub -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]' <playlist link>
```

##### Best quality video and best quality audio merged + Preferred resolution + Download video Creator’s uploaded specific language’s subtitle

```
youtube-dl --write-sub --sub-lang en -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]'  <playlist link>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Your link is not a playlist.**

A proper playlist URL looks like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHSdFJ8BDqEyvUUzm6R0HxawSWniP2c9K
```

Your URL is just the first video **OF** a certain playlist. It contains `https://www.youtube.com/watch?` instead of `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?`.

Pick the playlist by clicking on the title of the playlist on the right side in the list of videos and use this URL.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the `v=...&` part from the url, and only keep the `list=...` part. The main problem being the special character `&`, interpreted by the shell.

You can also quote your 'url' in your command.

More information here (for instance) :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/564567/how-to-download-playlist-from-youtube-dl

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to create a `file.txt` file and pass the link url link so:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Lj1BF0Kn8c&list=PL9YFoJnn53xyf9GNZrtiraspAIKc80s1i
```

make sure to include the `-a` parameter in terminal:

```
youtube-dl -a file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, workaround for this problem could be simple replacing `&` symbol with it's encoded version  `%26`

For those who are struggling with this problem while doing it through PHP (e.g. `shell_exec()`) , solution could be
`str_replace("&", "%26", $shell_command);`